# Comment a code line in PHP after first run?

Tags: php

Suppose that we have this code in only one PHP file:

```
<?php
migrateTables();
...
```

Now we want to run this PHP file and then that code need to convert to this:

```
<?php
// migrateTables();
...
```

Is it possible to write **//** in this file with PHP in this file, because there is no another file?
migrateTables() in my case is a function to create DB and tables in MySQL in each server. I want to run it in each server only one time. But it can be a general question too.

Comment: Why you do not use if?

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic I want to run once that code without any condition on server side.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please [edit] your question and add what you have tried that isn't working as expected.

Comment: You can write to file but you have to get that file content, explode to lines, add // to line you want, implode it with \n and put to file again. file_get_content and file_put_content with permissions set.

Comment: @Dave I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic That is good but what happen when I write on this file with a command on this file? Is it possible or I should add this solution to another file?

Comment: @iazaran Aha, honestly, I never tried to write to a file that is executed. Try and tell us :).

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic I added this code in my file: ```$path_to_file = dirname(__DIR__) . '/public/index.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("migrateTables();","//migrateTables();",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents); ``` And didn't work but without error. But from another file that works fine. I think I should to update another file in all servers with this code.

Comment: @iazaran Tnx for the feedback. Never tried that. Have a luck.

Comment: PHP reads the file and compiles it before executing it, so it's fine to modify the file that's being executed.

Comment: Why not just `$path_to_file = __FILE__;`?

Comment: @Barmar I added the codes to do that but didn't work. I should to use another file to add my codes and write to this file. This solution worked now but this is not an answer.

Comment: This seems like a horrible way to do what you want. Save the information about whether the data has been migrated in a file or in the database, and have the script check that.

Comment: @Barmar That is a good advice for __FILE__. Yes I should to use your advice too to beautify my codes.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have gotten plenty of help with the desired solution in the comments, so I'm going to touch on something important:

Something seems really dangerous about what you're doing here. If the intention of commenting out your `migrateTables()` function is to ensure that it runs only once, then there are two possibilities here:

1. This function is being executed in a script that is only accessible by an administrator account or on the local filesystem, i.e. a script that is not publicly accessible.
2. This function is being executed in a script that is publicly accessible, e.g. your website's homepage.

If we're talking about case #1, then why use such a convoluted method for table migration? Create a separate directory. Whenever you're rolling out updates that require table migrations or other various changes, have your main script parse this directory for scripts that need to be run, run those scripts, then delete them afterward (or move them elsewhere). In this case, have a `migrate_tables.php` file that only runs the `migrateTables()` function, which will be removed after the migrations are completed. There are other options available to you as well, and none of them will result in `migrateTables()` executing multiple times as long as you're careful about what you're doing.

If we're talking about #2, then stop what you're doing right this second. If this `migrateTables()` function is invoked upon a user visiting your website, then it's very easily possible for one instance of your script to execute `migrateTables()` when user A visits your website, and a second instance of your script to executed `migrateTables()` when user B visits your website before user A's instance has finished executing, which means commenting out the function after it finishes isn't enough to guarantee that it will only ever be run once. Requests to PHP are stateless and asynchronous, which means these requests may execute in parallel and result in some very, very nasty errors.

---

The takeaway is this: make sure you're not wasting your time on implementing a solution to the wrong problem, otherwise you may find that where you originally had just one small problem, you now have one small problem and one very big problem.

Comment: @b-fleming I need something like #1. But because of there is no admin after release apps, so I'm going to add some info to DB (like migration info in Laravel) and then check them with new structures. If something new found in structures, migrations run automatically, otherwise no. You are right about the problem. I wanted to run away from best solutions, but now I'm going to implement the best one. Thanks